# R automatic names modification

Tags: r

I stumbled upon this weird behavior in R:

```
> a = 5
> names(a) <- "bar"
> b = c(foo = a)
> names(b)
[1] "foo.bar"
```

Why do the names get concatenated/stacked?

I found this `c(a=b)` syntax in a script, but I couldn't find documentation about it. Is there any documentation for that?

Comment: In help page to `c` (`?c`) is mentioned that function preserve names. On other hand what output you expect: `"foo"` or `"bar"`?

Comment: `c` is R's concatenate function

Comment: @Marek I would have expected just `"foo"`, as `foo = a` looks like redefining the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do the names get
>   concatenated/stacked?

Because it preserves all the name information that was present before the concatenation.  If you don't like it, use `unname`.

> I found this c(a=b) syntax in a
>   script, but I couldn't find
>   documentation about it. Is there any
>   documentation for that?

Some of the examples on the `?c` page demonstrate `c(name = value)` behaviour, but there isn't much more to it than that.  You might also want to look at `?names`.

Answer (score 1):

It might also be instructive to see what happens if `a` is a vector; in this case if `foo=a` just redefined the name, all elements of the vector would end up with the same name.  Instead, as in the following example, the four elements end up with unique names, which can be nice.

```
> a <- c(A=1, B=2)
> b <- c(A=3, B=4)
> c(a=a, b=b)
a.A a.B b.A b.B 
  1   2   3   4
```